# Will there be two cats in the box (superposition) if I use virtual particles (magnetic field) to open the box in Schrodinger's experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse, schroedingers-cat

I have read this question:

[How does a Wavefunction collapse?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151457/how-does-a-wavefunction-collapse)

Where annav says:

> > More specifically, what conditions cause a wavefunction for a quantum particle to collapse?
> >
> > A measurement, i.e. interaction with particles on mass shell in a Feynman diagram ( real in contrast to virtual which are a mathematical tool). An instance picked from the predicted probability distribution of the wavefunction squared.

Now I was wondering, if I use a magnetic field to open the box of Schrodinger's cat experiment, that is made up (interacts with) of virtual particles.

Since the box only interacts in this case with the magnetic field, and the magnetic field interacts (with the box) with virtual particles, the wavefunction should not collapse.

Yes I get it, the collapse is just a fancy expression, nothing collapses, it just means that a measurement was made on the QM system (the box).

But in this case, I make the measurement (the interaction with virtual particles), so the wavefunction should not collapse (meaning the QM system remains in superposition).

This question is not specific for the Schrodinger experiment, it could be any QM experiment, the bottom line is whether using a magnetic field (that interacts with virtual particles) to make the measurement causes the QM system to remain in superposition or not?

Question:

1. if I open the box with a magnetic field (that interacts with virtual particles), will that collapse the wavefunction or will the QM system remain in superposition?
2. will there be two cats in the box (superposition)? if the statement is true, and virtual particles will not collapse the wavefunction, will the cats stay in superposition?

Comment: If I only have virtual particles  I do not have a measurement. The magnetic field has to have real particles as an output.: for example  moving electrons that will show a hit

Comment: We *never* observe a system in superposition. What would "two cats" even look like? Superposition happens only when there is no observation. The [open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem) about wavefunction "collapse" is *what is a measurement?*, it is not (and has never been) *what kind of measurement does collapse the wavefunction?*.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin if you see a cat moving at some velocity, then by the uncertainty principle you must also be seeing a superposition of cats in different positions.