# Wavefunction superposition state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

Before measurement the wavefunction of a quantum particle, eg an electron, evolves in a superposition state. Can the following wavefunction
$$\Psi = 1\,\,\lvert \uparrow \rangle + 0  \,\,\lvert \downarrow \rangle$$ in priciple also be considered as a superposition (conservation of probabilities), or does it describe already and only the "collapsed" eigenstate?

Comment: Wavefunctions are solutions of specific wave equations, if there is a "colapse" it means there was an interaction, and after the interaction a **new** wavefunction describes the probabilities for the electron. my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151457/how-does-a-wavefunction-collapse/151522#151522 is extensive and the other answers too.

Comment: $\Psi = 1\,\,\lvert \uparrow \rangle + 0  \,\,\lvert \downarrow \rangle$ and $\Psi = \lvert \uparrow \rangle$ are identical. So yes, $\Psi$ describes the "already collapsed eigenstate."